# Is php switch statement bug?

Tags: php

I have a problem want to know answer,
Why the following code will print A not default?

```
$i = 0;
switch ($i) {
    case 'A':
        echo "i equals A"; //will printed it
        break;
    case 'B':
        echo "i equals B";
        break;
    case 'C':
        echo "i equals C";
        break;
    default:
       echo "i equals other";
}
```

Anyone can tell me why? I truely don't understand .
My PHP version is 5.2.17 
Theanks.

Comment: 99.999999999999999999% of the time if you think you have found a bug in php, you haven't, its a bug\misunderstanding in your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This comparison is happening:

```
0 == 'A'
```

What happens is that PHP casts the string to an integer. This results in the letter A becoming zero because it doesn't represent a number.

Hence:

```
0 == 0
```

And that case meets the switch, and is therefore executed. Very counter-intuitive, but it's the way PHP's type system works, and is unfortunately technically not a bug.

You can solve this by turning `$i` into a string like this:

```
switch ((string) $i) {
```

Or by just initializing it as a string if you can:

```
$i = '0';
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful to know. I think I ran into this last month and solved it, but I wasn't sure *how* I solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that (int)0 equals to (string)A.

Try changing `$i = 0;` to `$i = '0';`, it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

$i is an integer, and you're comparing to a string. PHP will typecast that string ('A') to an integer, which makes it actually be 0 as well, so yes... in PHP-land, `'A' == 0` is TRUE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you're right but only one best answer in here sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
if ($i == 'A')
{
    echo 'woo';
}
```

and visit this href: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0):

This should work.You should convert in to string as switch case are in cases;

```
<?
$i = 0;
$i = (string)$i;
switch ($i) {
    case 'A':
        echo "i equals A"; //will printed it
        break;
    case 'B':
        echo "i equals B";
        break;
    case 'C':
        echo "i equals C";
        break;
    default:
       echo "i equals other";
}

?>
```